# Reload just the partial view [ASP.NET MVC]

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a form "Create" implemented an a partial view associated with post method "Create",how to reload just this partial view when firing POST method, without reloading all the page containing my partial

Answer (score 0):

If you submit the whole form than you need to render the whole page again.

You can send the AJAX request though and bring back only the partial view. You can then replace the part of the DOM with the new content.

Comment: I want to render only the partial containing my form

Comment: Than you need to perform an AJAX request to an action that returns a partial view.